# Let $A \in GL_n(K)$. Show $A$ can be transformed in a diagonal matrix with coefficients $1$ except the last one which is $\det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A \in GL_n(K)$. Show $A$ can be transformed in a diagonal matrix with coefficients $1$ except the last one which is $\det A$ *using only elementary row operations*.

I have proved $A$ can be transformed in a matrix whose first column is the first vector of the canonical basis. I would process by induction but I do not control the top coefficients (which have to be zeros). Do you have an idea how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

In the inductive step, after you transforming $\boldsymbol A$ into a matrix like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \boldsymbol \alpha^{\mathsf T}\\  \boldsymbol 0 & \boldsymbol B_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

how does the determinant change? And it is valid to apply inductive hypothesis now? After this, could you now cancel the first row?

P.S. I assume that by "*elementary line operations*" , you mean "elementary row operations". If I was wrong, please let me know.

Comment: $a$ is necessarily $\det A$ since  the determinant does not change (applying the hypothesis to B which size is <n). It is esay to cancel the first row (without $a$) using $B$.

Comment: @Lucas Actually in my mind, if I want to proceed by induction, I 'd rather make $a$ to be 1 and scale the last row so $\boldsymbol B$ has the same determinant as $\boldsymbol A$. Then I could apply the hypothesis to the $\boldsymbol B$ block. Finally I could use the diagonal matrix obtained from $\boldsymbol B$ to cancel the first row and complete the proof. Your method seems to be direct now.

Answer (score 0):

Using elementary row operations, transform the matrix to an upper triangular matrix, with the following modifications . . .

- Don't scale the last row except when also scaling another row.

  When scaling any row other than the last, also scale the last row by the inverse (reciprocal) scale factor.

  After swapping two rows, negate the last row if the rows that were swapped were an odd distance apart.

At the end, scale each row except the last to get a diagonal value of $1$, simultaneously scaling the last row by the inverse scale factor.

Each step leaves the determinant unchanged, so the last diagonal entry must equal the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to do some operations both before *and after* applying the induction hypothesis.

The starting case for induction would be $n=1$, in which case there are no operations needed (or possible), and the unique entry of the matrix equals its determinant.

In the induction step $n>1$, and then you can apply row operations to make the first column equal to that of the identity matrix. This requires a bit of work, but you claim to have done this. Note that development of the determinant of the modified matrix by the first column, which should give the value $\pm\det A$ and can be arranged to give ${+}\det A$, results in the determinant of the lower right ḃlock $B$ of size $(n-1)\times(n-1)$; in particular this determinant is nonzero and $B\in GL_{n-1}(K)$.

Now by the induction hypothesis, there is a sequence of row operations that transforms $B$ into its corresponding diagonal with lower-right entry $\det(B)=\det(A)$. This same sequence can be applied to the last $n-1$ rows of the matrix from which $B$ was extracted, which rows have an additional leading$~0$, but these entries are unaffected by the row operations. The result is a matrix with the main diagonal and its last $n-1$ lines as they should be, but with uncontrolled entries in the first row, after the first column. Now simply apply row operations from each of the final $n-1$ rows towards the first row to clear these uncontrolled entries out (since $\det A$ is invertible, there is no problem to do this in the final column.)